# Data validation in CakePHP doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I don't know why this doesn't work (I am using CakePHP 2.1 and also tried 2.0):

Here is Model

```
class User extends AppModel
    {
        public $validate = array('username' => array('rule' => 'email'));
    }
```

Here is Controller

```
class UsersController extends AppController
    {
        function index()
        {
            $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all') );
        }

        function add()
        {
             if (!empty($this->request->data)) 
             {            
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) 
                {                
                    $this->Session->setFlash('User has been registered.');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));            
                }        
             }
        }
    }
```

Here is add View

```
<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Register');
?>
```

And it validates whatever I write... And it should check if username is email...

It's impossible! It has to work! - but it doesn't...

I also checked it with cake php 2.0 and it still does't work - please help, it is so simple i has to work...

Maybe something with my db table is wrong???

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
   `username` varchar(50),
   `password` varchar(50),
   `created` datetime,
   `modified` datetime,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9;
```

This is very strange - in my app folder I only add 'UserModel.php', 'UserController.php' and 'add.ctp', and a db config - all that I wrote above - and validation doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the `$validate` array is not declared correctly.

Try this:

```
$validate = array('username' => array(
                        'email' => array(
                            'rule' => array('email')
                        )));
```

or this:

```
$validate = array('username' => 'email');
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Comment: I have already tried it, and it's still the same - and I read this chapter and I am doing everything exactly like it should be done and it still doesn't work - I don't know what to do! Maybe if it works for you, you could send me model/view/controller + database script on alek.barszczewski@gmail.com?

Comment: You're right sorry. Your syntax seems correct as well. I always use my first example, because this is what `cake bake` generates. Then I don't know. You should probably debug the invalidFields() in Model.php from the core. For example, to start, you could verify that the $validate array is what you want if you put a `debug($this->validate)` in this function.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I know what is wrong:

1. my model filename was called 'UserModel.php' and it should be 'User.php'
2. At start of file 'User.php' I had to put 'App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');'

Answer (score 1):

You should write in your controller ( UserController )

```
($this-User->set($this->request->data)
```

before the function validates Like you see;

```
 function add()
    {
         if (!empty($this->request->data)) 
         {     $this->User->set($this->request->data);
            if ($this->User->validates()) 
            {   $this->User->save($this->request->data)
                $this->Session->setFlash('User has been registered.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));            
            }        
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O.k... this is what I do (also changing the username to an email)

```
$components = array('Auth' => array('authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')))), 'Email');
```

This works. In CakePHP 1.3 you had to specify both the username (email) and the password. So when I moved to CakePHP 2.1 I continued doing the same thing and had no problems with the validation.

you can see all that you need here: [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html)

Comment: But I am not using auth component yet - so it should work normally and check if field 'username' is a valid email...

Comment: Sorry... I didn't notice that you were not using the Auth component... My bad. Now that I take a closer look... Why don't you change the table so you have an Email field instead of a Username field? why have a username and treat it as an email instead of just having an Email?

Comment: And also I don't care for now on logging in user but registering them so it should be basic UserModel save...